# cloudera sandbox - docker run error mac m1

Tags: docker, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am unable to run the docker container on mac m1

Please note i was not able to run the below docker container

## Reference

https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/sandbox-cdh

## my system configuration

ram 16 gb
sdd - 250 gb and free space is 150 gb

## command used --> cloudera/sandbox-cdh --> not working

```
docker run -m 10G --hostname=sandbox-cdh.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -v /Users/appleworld/Documents/Docker:/Src --publish-all=true -p 8888 -p 7180:7180 cloudera/sandbox-cdh /usr/bin/sandbox-cdh.cloudera --platform amd64
```

## Error

```
Unable to find image 'cloudera/sandbox-cdh:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for cloudera/sandbox-cdh:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

is there an issue with the command ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because image have no `latest` tag.

```
> docker pull cloudera/sandbox-cdh
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for cloudera/sandbox-cdh:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Use with correct [tag](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/sandbox-cdh/tags) `cloudera/sandbox-cdh:6.3.0`.

```
> docker pull cloudera/sandbox-cdh:6.3.0                             
6.3.0: Pulling from cloudera/sandbox-cdh
ac9208207ada: Pulling fs layer
b7bb5062434d: Pulling fs layer
...
```

Comment: @medaasx - Many thanks but when i execute the docker run command i am not able to spin the docker container all the services are not getting started

Comment: Please update the question, referred `not found` error seems to be resolved.

Comment: i got this error - Failed to mount tmpfs at /run: Operation not permitted

Failed to mount cgroup at /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd: Operation not permitted

[!!!!!!] Failed to mount API filesystems, freezing.

Comment: Add `--tmpfs /run` that should do the trick.

Comment: docker --tmpfs /run -m 10G --hostname=sandbox-cdh.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -v /Users/appleworld/Documents/Docker:/Src --publish-all=true -p 8888 -p 7180:7180 cloudera/sandbox-cdh /usr/bin/sandbox-cdh.cloudera --platform amd64

Comment: `docker run --tmpfs /run ...`